# FaceBook. All comments are collected on one page

Tags: facebook

The site is set for social plugin Facebook commenting to different pages.
The goal is to bring up a page to all comments left within the boundaries of the site.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ - One of the FAQs is **How do I access the comments left on my site?** and shows how to retrieve comments programmatically - you can then display them however you wish

The example given pulls the comments left on the Comments plugin documentation - 
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments